# How to convert currencies in python?

Tags: python, list, currency

I'm working on a virtual assistant project. I want it to tell me the dollar rate in other currencies. 
I have written following code using beautifulsoup which gets data from given website, parses it and prints the results in the command line for me to read. But this is just for USD to PKR. How do I modify the program so it takes any currency and tells me the conversion rates for that currency? 
e.g if I ask it "What is Dollar rate in Britain?", "what is GBP rate in UAE", "What is Euro rate in USA?" and it returns me the conversion rate. The code I'm referring to is given below.

```
import urllib.request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

currency_page = 'http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=PKR'
currency = urllib.request.urlopen(currency_page)
currency_data = BeautifulSoup(currency, 'html.parser')

USD = currency_data.find('span', attrs={'class': 'uccResultUnit'})
USD_PKR = USD.text.strip() # strip() is used to remove starting and trailing
print(USD_PKR)
```

I tried editing the URL `http://www.xe.com/currencyconverter/convert/?Amount=1&From=USD&To=PKR` 
and replacing **`Amount=1, From=USD, To=PKR`**

with *`Amount= custom_amount, From= any_source_curreny, To=any_target_currency`* and passing multiple currency names to the variable but I'm confusedd with this. Can anyone suggest how to do this? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use an API instead of scraping a web page?

Comment: forex - https://pypi.python.org/pypi/forex-python

Comment: The results will be sent to TTS engine and it will speak it for me. That's why I scrapped it. Does API provide such thing?

Answer (score 1):

An easy solution to this is to construct your url dynamically based on user input (you can use [*`str.format()`*](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-examples) to do that). For example:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from requests import get
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import sys

v1 = sys.argv[1]
v2 = sys.argv[2]
amount = sys.argv[3]

# check if the values passed are valid
# and construct the url like so:
currency_page = 'http://www......../convert/?Amount={}&From={}&To={}'.format(amount,v1,v2)

currency = get(currency_page).text
currency_data = BeautifulSoup(currency, 'html.parser')

USD = currency_data.find('span', attrs={'class': 'uccResultUnit'})
USD_PKR = USD.text.strip()
print(USD_PKR)
```

---

Results:

```
$ ./test.py EUR PKR 1                           
1 EUR = 125.790 PKR
```

The other solution, as also mentioned in the comments, is to use

1. an API or
2. a module instead.

Comment: it returns the error:

urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request

Comment: @Tauseef_Ahmed did you replace the before `/convert` url-part in my post with the original one ? I didn't post the actual url for typical reasons! Also I tried the code and worked fine for me (I use `requests` instead of `urllib`)